What's the name of this english-speaking movie where a man has to care for an elder man (maybe his father)?
Color movie, picture quality I have in my mind makes me believe it's from the 90s or 2000s, but I might be wrong, as I saw it partially on TV a bit more than 10 years ago.
The atmosphere looks a bit more  european than american, but not as to definitely ignore other possibilities.
Apparently a middle-age man has an elder moving in together (probably his father/father-in-law) because of increasing physical/mental illnesses of the age or something like that.
I sorta remember the man having dark hair, and the elder being really old, pretty wrinkled skin and almost surely bald or with little hair, all gray.
In one scene the man finds a dirty diaper under his bed, and subsequently (or in another scene altogether, I wouldn't know) he snaps at him and yells lots of things, "SHAKE SHAKE SHAKE" being among his words.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it showing?  Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Thank you for the corrections! Well, I had read the guide you indicated, but unfortunately I don't know much more than what I've said... I might try to give a shot at their appearance though!
